# Mobile search screen button layout (Search|Reset)

Tags: mobile, buttons

I am contemplating the layout of search page buttons for a mobile app (iOS).

The buttons are located at the bottom of a scrollable table view.

Here is my current layout:

[image: Current layout]

I have been noticing recently that the 'Reset Filters' button seems a bit too prominent, so we have been talking about just using a simple link (either blue or red with an underline).

Something along these lines: (The link would either be above or below the search button).

[image]

This just seems a little lop-sided, though.

Another alternative is to place the buttons side by side:
[image]

Another idea is to adapt option 1 or 3 to use a gray background for the reset button. That might take a bit of focus away from the destructive action.

What do you guys think is the best solution? Or is there a better solution that has not been mentioned?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you visually (and proximately) associating both Reset and Search together? They're not exactly similar features; one destroys everything you've done and the other actions it. Way too much chance of hitting the wrong one.

Comment: Why do you have a Reset Filters function?

Comment: @Erics There are a lot of search options. It would be cumbersome to the user to have to set each one to the default value.

Comment: proximity is the issue more than anything in this case, IMHO. In all those examples, they are just too close to be a 'safe' target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to JonW's comment, I would try putting the "reset filters" button at the top-right corner. It is harder to hit by mistake there, also it doesn't make sense to scroll all the way down, reset your filters, then scroll back up to set them again.

Answer (score 0):

The Search feature could be in your top navigation bar or sidebar, based on how important searching is in your app. 


As for Reset Filters, typically it's common practice to include it at the bottom (or top) of the list of filter options. Reasons for this would be

- The only time you'd want to clear filters is when you're choosing filters and then decide that they're inadequate. Then, you'd tend to look at the bottom (or top) of the list for an option to start over.